# Overlay with cut out rectangle mask

Tags: css, overlay

Scenario: **I want to cover an element by a rectangular mask** (background #000 with opacity 0.8, for example). Next, there's an area in the covered area for which I want to highlight.

Here is a sample screenshot:

[image: Overlay with rectangular cut out mask]

(As you notice, there' s a rectangle cut from the darken mask. In Photoshop, it's easy - just place a layer on top and cut the rectangle out).

How could I make it work in CSS?

Side note: This kind of trick seems to be used a lot for "educating users about new features".

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helps! I upvoted but forgot to mark it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use border or box-shadows for this. And use them on a pseudo element to minimize markup.

Example with box-shadows :

```css
div{
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.overlay{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.overlay:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 9999px rgba(0,0,0,.85);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some content</p>
  <p class="overlay">Other content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever idea! Def going to try this!

Comment: This might not work if you're applying this to a deeply-nested dom element and other elements up the chain have z-index set (and you want the overlay to overlay everything).  In that case I've found you need to define the overlay window at the top level and use js to position the highlight window over the item you want to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `z-index` to display the highlighted element above the overlay like this:

```
.overlay{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:999;
}

.highlight{
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmRRVg)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. We cannot assume anything about the element/graphics under the black mask.

Comment: This is my understanding of what you have explained. Sorry if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This Can be done only in webkit at the moment. using the property `-webkit-mask-box-image`. other than that we can't achieve this only using css.

Comment: So what if he agrees on using JavaScript, how could we achieve it that way?